# intellij - way to do the eclipse CTRL+ALT+UP duplicate lines upwards and end up with carets in duplicated field?

Tags: macros, intellij-idea, shortcut, hotkeys

I want to duplicate just like the standard CTRL+D hotkey in intellij, but in the eclipse version was a way to end up in the duplicated lines with the caret. E.g. the original is at the bottom and you are set to edit the duplicated lines at the top with the caret.

E.g. CTRL+D does this

```
| <-- caret


originaltext|   (hit CTRL+D) you end up with

duplicatedoriginaltext
originaltext|

but what i want
duplicatedoriginaltext|
originaltext
```

is there a way to do this in intellij?
and obviously this has to work with several lines as well.

Comment: An intellij plugin can do this. If you put a bounty of +100 I could write it for you :)

Comment: Agreed, it would nice if IDEA had this "duplicate up" and "duplicate down" features but I don't think it does.

Answer (score 14):

IntelliJ has a feature similar to eclipse's `CTRL+ALT+DOWN` feature.  It's not set by default, and you can set it in the `Keymap` under the `Editor Actions` grouping. Its called `Duplicate Lines`.

[image: IntelliJ Keymap]

Answer (score 12):

A bit late to the party but I created a plugin to do just that:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10008-duplicate-lines

[image]

Supports single lines, multiple selected lines, multiple carets and block selection.

Default shortcuts are "Shift + Ctrl + Alt + Up/Down" and "Shift + Command + Option + Up/Down" for macOS.

And is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA, PhpStorm, WebStorm, PyCharm, RubyMine, AppCode, CLion, Gogland, DataGrip, Rider, MPS and Android Studio.

Source code: https://github.com/xusoo/duplicate-lines-intellij-plugin

Comment: Sorry, it was not intentionally spam, is just a simple plugin I made for myself and I wanted to share. Anyway, I added some more information ;) Actually, I think now seems more like spam, like I'm trying to sell it haha

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you how I solved this problem. I use Autohotkey and just mapped Ctrl+Alt+Up to duplicate line, then move the line up.

Comment: I'm guessing this might only work for a single line selection unless [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can see the size of the selection.  (also note, windows-only)

Comment: Could you post the ahk script section? Thanks.